# TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() returns a constant value?

Tags: java, android

I'm generating a key for obfuscate information.

That key must change between devices so for the generation I was using:

- `Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID)`
- `TelephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber()`
- `TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()`
- A random persistent String generated if all of the options above are `null`

But testing I realised that since **TelephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber()** changes with the SIM in the device (and in airplane mode always return null) the key also changes and the obfuscated data cant be recovered.

My question is: Does **TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()** return always the same value (null or a value but always the same result)?

Note: I tested and it returns a valid value for me even in "Airplane mode"

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) for info related to unique ID. It is important to note that the ID you are pulling can also change when a device is factory reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the device in question is **not** rooted (as it allows the user to change most of the unique strings of the device) TelephonyManager.getDeviceId() should return the IMEI number on GSM network - This is linked to handset not SIM and so, it will not change.

Comment: Rooted device users may be able to change this value, and alternative ROMs might allow the user to change this value.